# Uniqueness of coefficients in infinite sin series $a(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{i} \sin(n x) =0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

if we can say

$$a(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \sin(n x) =0, \forall x$$

does this generally imply that *all* constant coefficients $a_i$ should be zero, or can I construct any number of solutions that may provide the right cancellations to make it zero?

My intuition for superposition of different modes of $\sin(nx)$ is that if $a_i$ is always same-signed (I *might* be able to show this in my application), then this should be unique, but if each coefficient can have a different sign then it could be anything.

I was looking for someone to confirm or deny what I was thinking, and maybe point me towards more mathematical ideas about why that is so.

Comment: What about the case $x=\pi$.

Comment: More generally the case $x=k\pi$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The idea for this problem is that the overall sum should be zero for all values of x. So even if $sin(nx)$ for a particular value of x is zero, the corresponding coefficient $a_n$ should be acting to make sure that the nonzero-values of $sin(nx)$ are contributing to the overall function $a(x)=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Yes it's true if you assume convergence - check reference for the theory of Riemann trigonometric series but the idea is that integrating twice you get an absolutely convergent trigonometric series equal to a polynomial and that forces the polynomial constant and then zero, but there are tricky convergence issues

Comment: Hi @Conrad - just to clarify, under those assumptions do you mean it is "true" that it is unique (and uniquely zero) or that it is true that there are a number of solutions? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is true the trigonometric series is unique if it converges everywhere - in jargon it means the empty set is a set of uniqueness for trigonometric series

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand the comments in an answer: there are two concepts here - trigonometric series and Fourier series:

Let $S$ be $\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n \geq 1}{(a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx))}$, where $a_n, b_n$ are complex numbers; then S is called a trigonometric series and the Riemann theory of such series tries to associate to $S$ some meaning and deal with issues of unicity of the meaning etc.

**IF** $a_n, b_n$ come from an absolutely integrable (Lebesgue) periodic function $f$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ by the usual formulas $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\sin(nx)dx$, S is called a Fourier series and it satisfies some properties like $a_n, b_n$ converge to zero (Riemann-Lebesgue lemma), $S$ is Cesaro (also called Feijer in this context) and Abel (also called radial) summable to $f$ though it may not be convergent anywhere to $f$ (Kolmogorov 1920's or so), while if $f$ is continuos, a famous theorem of Carleson (1960's) shows that $S$ converges a.e to $f$ (while a classic theorem of Feijer (1910's) shows that $S$ is uniformly Cesaro (and Abel) summable to $f$.

The distinction between trigonometric and Fourier series is non-trivial even if we are given that $a_n, b_n$ converge to zero in a positive decreasing manner as the series $\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\log n}$ is convergent everywhere, uniformly convergent on any compact set that doesn't contain an integral multiple of $2\pi$ including zero, so its sum is a continuous function except at $0$ and integral multiples of $2\pi$, but it is **NOT** a Fourier series; on the other hand its conjugate cosine sum $\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\log n}$ is uniformly convergent on compact sets outside integral multiples of $2\pi$, $\infty$ at such and its sum is integrable so the cosine series **IS** a Fourier series.

In general, if $S$ can be associated to a function $f$ in a strong enough manner (absolute convergence, uniform convergence, $L^p$ convergence, $p \geq 1$, other more esoteric forms of convergence) then $S$ is the Fourier series of $f$, so people generally study only Fourier series for that reason but as noted pointwise convergence or a.e uniform convergence are not good enough.

As unicity goes: for **Fourier** series a.e convergence is enough to give it - so if we know **apriori** that a trigonometric series comes from an integrable function by the formulas above and the series converges a.e to $0$, all the coefficients are $0$. However the proof requires work (follows from Feijer theorem) as simple integration of $S$ against $\cos(nx), \sin(nx)$ and the use of the ortogonality relations for those to conclude is not justified unless we have strong assumptions on $S$ like uniformly bounded partial sums a.e etc

However for a general trigonometric series while convergence on a set of non-zero measure implies $a_n, b_n$ going to zero (Cantor-Lebesgue lemma), the rest of the issues are considerably more complicated and they are treated by what is called the Riemann theory of trigonometric series which was at its apogee in the 1920's when the Russian school led by N Bary obtained almost definitive results regarding unicity and the like; in essence **convergence everywhere or even on a set with countable complement** **implies unicity** (so indeed the answer to the original question is true) but the proof is complicated (though known from Riemann), while for more general sets of zero measure, convergence a.e outside them may or may not imply unicity and while a full classification is not quite known as the property  of such to be "unicity sets" seem to depend on arithmetic not topological properties, lots of results are known. However simple summability (Abel, Cesaro) etc is not very useful here as for example the Poisson kernel is Abel summable to $0$ everywhere except at $1$ but its coefficients definitely do not go to zero at infinity.

Comment: Hi @Conrad thanks for the in depth response and sorry ive not accepted it yet or got back to you - gonna take me a day or two to find the time to get to grips with this (I'm not much of a mathematician!)

Comment: No problem - the issues are quite deep for general coefficients, though easier under assumptions like absolute convergence

Answer (score -1):

Note that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(m\theta)\sin(n\theta)\,d\theta=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\cos((n-m)\theta) - \cos((n+m)\theta)\,d\theta = 0$$if $m\ne \pm n$.
And when $m = n$, the integral is $\pi$.

Now, what is $\int_0^{2\pi}a(x)\sin(mx)\,dx$?

Comment: thanks for the hint. 

From this I reckon that $\int_{0}^{\2\pi} a(x)\sin(mx)\mathrm{dx} = 0$ (as a(x) =0). Then substituting the series form of $a(x)$ in gives  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \int_0^{2\pi} sin(nx) sin(mx) =0$. Because of orthogonality, each coefficient will only have one non-zero evaluation of the integral, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \pi a_n =0$

So this means the sum of the coefficients must be zero? Does this extra info give me enough to make my mind up on whether every coefficient should be zero or if it just suffices that the sum to zero?

Comment: The answer above is true only under strong additional assumptions like uniform convergence or bounded partial series so we can integrate term by term. For example there are trigonometric series that converge a.e.to zero with non_zero coefficients while the above answer would contradict that since changing an integral on a zero set doesn't change its value; one of the goals of the branch of analysis - quite popular in the 1920's when close to complete results were obtained - that goes under the name Riemann trigonometric series is to see when can we integrate such series and get unicity

Comment: Even if the original series is a Fourier series, not a general trigonometric series, and the proof of unicity is simpler, it still requires some work as naive term by term integration doesn't work without strong conditions on the series - one way is to use the Feijer kernel